# Yet another issue with xpath and namespaces

Tags: c, xml, xpath

Cause I'm not able to register

```
http://www.spotify.com/ns/music/1
```

namespace I'm using the following

```
/*[name()='tracks']/*[name()='track']/*[name()='name']
```

string to retrieve track name. The problem is that I want only first track name, is there any workaround for selecting only first track block?

```
<tracks xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns="http://www.spotify.com/ns/music/1">
<opensearch:Query role="request" startPage="1" searchTerms="hypo disco"/>
<opensearch:totalResults>2</opensearch:totalResults>
<opensearch:startIndex>0</opensearch:startIndex>
<opensearch:itemsPerPage>100</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
<track href="spotify:track:5uYWzsjWBui67Au7AwfLMC">
<name>Killed Banano - Disco Version</name>
<artist href="spotify:artist:2XtRg7z3aq8UsX1fstLJKM">
<name>Hypo</name>
</artist>
<id type="isrc">FR6V80402639</id>
<album href="spotify:album:2r2lvkRFTGXDXfNxUslgv7">
<name>Random Veneziano</name>
<released>2005</released>
<availability>
<territories>
AD AE AF AG AI AL AM AN AO AQ AR AS AT AU AW AX AZ BA BB BD BE BF BG BH BI BJ BM BN BO BR BS BT BV BW BY BZ CA CC CD CF CG CH CI CK CL CM CN CO CR CU CV CX CY CZ DE DJ DK DM DO DZ EC EE EG EH ER ES ET FI FJ FK FM FO FR GA GB GD GE GF GG GH GI GL GM GN GP GQ GR GS GT GU GW GY HK HM HN HR HT HU ID IE IL IN IO IQ IR IS IT JM JO JP KE KG KH KI KM KN KP KR KW KY KZ LA LB LC LI LK LR LS LT LU LV LY MA MC MD ME MG MH MK ML MM MN MO MP MQ MR MS MT MU MV MW MX MY MZ NA NC NE NF NG NI NL NO NP NR NU NZ OM PA PE PF PG PH PK PL PM PN PR PS PT PW PY QA RE RO RS RU RW SA SB SC SD SE SG SH SI SJ SK SL SM SN SO SR ST SV SY SZ TC TD TF TG TH TJ TK TL TM TN TO TR TT TV TW TZ UA UG UM US UY UZ VA VC VE VG VI VN VU WF WS YE YT ZA ZM ZW ZZ
</territories>
</availability>
</album>
<track-number>19</track-number>
<length>130.044000</length>
<popularity>0.02090</popularity>
</track>
<track href="spotify:track:2w2d0WyMqLwMEGZRGMiBDS">
<name>New Disco</name>
<artist href="spotify:artist:5ircLG6gSoS34Dh6AWNc6g">
<name>Estevon</name>
</artist>
<id type="isrc">ushm21309193</id>
<album href="spotify:album:0AGlfBGzKfBLE9fHU6eOHc">
<name>Estevon Presents Hypo-Hybrid</name>
<released>2013</released>
<availability>
<territories>worldwide</territories>
</availability>
</album>
<track-number>13</track-number>
<length>248.847000</length>
<popularity>0.00000</popularity>
</track>
</tracks>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only the first track name, then this should work:

```
(/*[local-name()='tracks']/*[local-name()='track']/*[local-name()='name'])[1]
```

Also if you wanna ignore the namespace, I'd suggest you use `local-name()` instead of just `name()`. For your case, it works just the same, but if there were a namespace prefix, `name()` would return it, whereas `local-name()` never will.

Comment: You could also just wildcard the namespaces, rather than use predicates, which I think looks neater: `/*:tracks/*:track[1]/*:name`